# Populate image in custom list view with hyperlink

Tags: json, image, listview, sharepoint-online

I'm quite new to JSON/coding and have been struggling to find a solution to display images within a custom list view. I'm using a custom [Content Navigator](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/content-navigator) view from github, and wish to display images within each selected field of content. This formatting does not work within gallery view.

Originally, my goal was to use the [Tabs custom list](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/tabs) view with the same goal of displaying the image per each tab. I gave up on that one though, it's still my preferred method.

[Attempt number 1 of the Content Navigator view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/505CN.png)

I have tried many ways to display the image over the past few weeks with today's attempts being:

- Used the Image column and uploaded the image itself. Then, used that column as the img src. This produced an errored image.
- Used getThumbnail
- Used hyperlink column instead of image column, then used .serverRelativeUrl to pull the image.

Thus far nothing has worked. I either get the errored image, or it's entirely blank. The goal is to have the metric's Title, Description, and Image all viewable within the section.

Current code to hyperlinked content:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "id": "='tool_' + @rowIndex"
    },
    "style": {
      "display": "block",
      "height": "240px"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "display": "flex",
          "align-items": "center"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "[$Title]",
            "style": {
              "font-size": "32px",
              "font-weight": "bold",
              "flex-grow": "1"
            }
          },
          {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
              "iconName": "ChromeBack",
              "href": "='#tool_' + (@rowIndex - 1)",
              "title": "Previous",
              "class": "ms-fontColor-themeLight ms-fontColor-themePrimary--hover"
            },
            "style": {
              "font-size": "18px",
              "text-decoration": "none",
              "padding": "8px",
              "display": "=if(@rowIndex == 0, 'none', 'inherit')"
            }
          },
          {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
              "iconName": "ChromeBackMirrored",
              "href": "='#tool_' + (@rowIndex + 1)",
              "title": "Next",
              "class": "ms-fontColor-themeLight ms-fontColor-themePrimary--hover"
            },
            "style": {
              "font-size": "18px",
              "text-decoration": "none",
              "padding": "8px"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "txtContent": "[$Content]",
        "style": {
          "font-size": "18px"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "img",
        "attributes": {
          "src": "[$Image.serverRelativeUrl]"
        },
        "style": {
          "position": "absolute",
          "width": "100%",
          "height": "auto"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Result:
[No errored image - just empty space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7cA0.png)